# Label references with custom foreign keys in rails fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, fixtures

I have a **lists** class with a customized foreign_key

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'author_id'
```

The table was created adding a reference and a foreign key as follows

```
add_reference :lists, :author, index: true
add_foreign_key :lists, :users, column: :author_id
```

Problem is, in my fixtures I'm trying to use label references but I keep getting a SQL exception
**table lists has no column named author**

```
lists.yml

list1:
    name: topchartsyea
    author: dude1
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible to use label references when using customized foreign keys like these?

Using rails 4.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're trying to use `author` when you've named the relationship `user`. If you want your fixture to work like that, then I think this should fix it up:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :author_id
```